# MVC4 : Manually set the validation message from the server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to validate some form fields in the server side, but I don't want to use Data Annotations Custom Validators.
I need to manually set its value based on the return of the called Business Layer Method to define this message.

Just as an example!

NEED:

If the given username already exists, the MVC4 validation error span shall display "This username already exists."

CODE:

```
 if (_business.UserNameExists(username))
 {
    // Set the field validation error span message
    // HOW TO DO??
 }
```

Comment: what is your question mate? sugestion by friend is not working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A friend came with the solution, it is very simple!

```
 if (_business.UserNameExists(username))
 {
    // Set the field validation error span message
    ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "This username already exists.");
 }
```

Where UserName is the name of the Entity attribute being validated.